# A commit in main branch automatically got added to new merge request in gitlab which was not required

Tags: git, gitlab

When I raised a new merge request from a new branch in git lab then a commit to main branch (for some other merge request which was already merged in main) got cherry picked automatically. But when my merge request got merged into main then I could see my change got reflected, but the one which got cherrypicked was not reflected. It showed the history as the old one only.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the scenario and what behavior is unexpected? Providing git logs (like maybe the output of `git log --all --decorate --oneline --graph` showing branch names and commit hashes) or even screenshots from GitLab may be helpful.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.